# Why is my Keras model performing so poorly on the Iris dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

I'm working through [this Keras tutorial](http://blog.fastforwardlabs.com/post/139921712388/hello-world-in-keras-or-scikit-learn-versus) and I'm finding something interesting.

I've trained my logistic regression model using the sklearn, and it performs fairly well:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils

# Load the iris dataset from seaborn.
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

# Use the first 4 variables to predict the species.
X, y = iris.values[:, 0:4], iris.values[:, 4]

# Split both independent and dependent variables in half
# for cross-validation
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.5, random_state=0)

# Train a scikit-learn log-regression model
lr = LogisticRegressionCV()
lr.fit(train_X, train_y)

# Test the model. Print the accuracy on the test data
pred_y = lr.predict(test_X)
print("Accuracy is {:.2f}".format(lr.score(test_X, test_y))) # Accuracy is 0.83
```

83% is quite good, but using deep learning we should be able to do better. I train a Keras model...

```
# Define a one-hot encoding of variables in an array.
def one_hot_encode_object_array(arr):
    '''One hot encode a numpy array of objects (e.g. strings)'''
    uniques, ids = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)
    return np_utils.to_categorical(ids, len(uniques))

# One-hot encode the train and test y's
train_y_ohe = one_hot_encode_object_array(train_y)
test_y_ohe = one_hot_encode_object_array(test_y)

# Build the keras model

model = Sequential()
# 4 features in the input layer (the four flower measurements)
# 16 hidden units
model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
# 3 classes in the ouput layer (corresponding to the 3 species)
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the keras model
model.fit(train_X, train_y_ohe, verbose=0, batch_size=1)

# Test the model. Print the accuracy on the test data
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_X, test_y_ohe, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy is {:.2f}".format(accuracy)) # Accuracy is 0.60????
```

When I train a Keras model, my accuracy is actually worse than my logistic regression model.

While this makes sense for some data, incredibly linearly separable data (like iris) should be very learnable for a Keras sequential model. I have tried increasing the number of hidden layers to 32, 64, and 128 and there was no improvement on the accuracy.

Below shows the Iris data (specifically the independent variables) as a function of the species (the dependent variable):

[image: Iris data]

Why is my model performing so poorly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've replaced the one_hot_encoding and just use keras' `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

The obvious thing to try is: **increase the number of epochs in learning** (default 10, let's try 100).

#### Code

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

# Load the iris dataset from seaborn.
iris = load_iris()

# Use the first 4 variables to predict the species.
X, y = iris.data[:, :4], iris.target

# Split both independent and dependent variables in half
# for cross-validation
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.5, random_state=0)

# Train a scikit-learn log-regression model
lr = LogisticRegressionCV()
lr.fit(train_X, train_y)

# Test the model. Print the accuracy on the test data
pred_y = lr.predict(test_X)
print("Accuracy is {:.2f}".format(lr.score(test_X, test_y))) # Accuracy is 0.83


# Build the keras model

model = Sequential()
# 4 features in the input layer (the four flower measurements)
# 16 hidden units
model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
# 3 classes in the ouput layer (corresponding to the 3 species)
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the keras model
model.fit(train_X, train_y, verbose=1, batch_size=1, nb_epoch=100)

# Test the model. Print the accuracy on the test data
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_X, test_y, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy is {:.2f}".format(accuracy))
```

#### Output

```
Accuracy is 0.83
Accuracy is 0.99
```

Comment: Thank you for share your script.